# Модернизация хвоста ссылки

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Делаю свое первое расширение под Google Chrome - большую часть уже сделал, и тут прямо тупику меня какой-то (**второй день ломаю голову**).
Имеем сайт `www.site.ru` и папку `smail`. Как сделать так, чтобы подставлялся хвост, например, пользователь заходит `www.site.ru/smail/dow` и тут `dow` меняется на `sociate`,
таким образом ссылка `www.site.ru/smail/dow` превращается в `www.site.ru/smail/sociate`

Ниже код, который получилось собрать, но похоже нужно что-то другое.

```
var host = "http://www.site/smail/sociate";  ////////////// КУДА 
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details)   {
         return {redirectUrl: host + details.url.match(/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+([\S\s]*)/)[1]};
    },
    {
        urls: [
            "http://www.site.ru/smail/*"  /////////// ОТКУДА
        ],
        types: []
    },
    ["blocking"]
);
```

Comment: у вас сервер есть?

Comment: а если попробовать
if(window.location == "http://www.site.ru/smail/") window.location = "http://www.site/smail/sociate"